# jQuery - localStorage for toggling hidden class

Tags: jquery, local-storage

By pressing `.trigger` the `hidden` class is toggled to show/hide the `.box`. I am trying to use `localStorage` to remember the last state of the `.box` i.e whether it has the hidden class or not.

How do I store whether each `.box` has class `hidden`, and then deliver the last selected state on page reload?

https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/ExNPNyy

```js
$(".box").toggleClass(localStorage.toggled);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".trigger").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this).closest(".item").find(".box");

    if (localStorage.toggled != "hidden") {
      $this.toggleClass("hidden", true);
      localStorage.toggled = "hidden";
    } else {
      $this.toggleClass("hidden", false);
      localStorage.toggled = "";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

.trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

.box {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.box.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="trigger"></div>
  <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="trigger"></div>
  <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to write a data item in the current domain's `localStorage` object is:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

The syntax for reading is as follows:

```
let key = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

In your code you're not following the above syntax, but trying to access to an unknown `localStorage.toggled` property.
You should fix your JS code like this:

```
$(".box").toggleClass(localStorage.getItem("toggled"));
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".trigger").on("click", function () {
    let $this = $(this).closest(".item").find(".box");
    if (localStorage.getItem("toggled") != "hidden") {
      $this.toggleClass("hidden", true);
      localStorage.setItem("toggled", "hidden");
    } else {
      $this.toggleClass("hidden", false);
      localStorage.setItem("toggled", "");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I am having trouble getting your code to run on each item. I have to double click the trigger to toggle the hidden class and it doesn't seem to be remembering the last state of the box on refresh: https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/ExNPNyy